# I have written Procedure based on condition assign value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROC Valtest( @job_id INT) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE @count    INT 
    DECLARE @response VARCHAR(50) 
    SELECT @count=Count(0) 
    FROM   employee 
    WHERE  job_id=@job_id 
    IF(@count = 0 ) 
    SET @response='No'; 
    ELSE 
    SET @response='Yes'; 
  ENDDECLARE @response VARCHAR(50)`enter code here`EXEC @response 
    =Valtest 5SELECT @response 
         --exec test 200
```

Comment: And do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Proper way:

```
CREATE PROC Valtest( @job_id INT) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM employee  WHERE  job_id=@job_id)
    SELECT 'Yes'; 
    ELSE 
    SELECT 'No'; 
END
```

Return statement from stored procedure indicates the status - `0` procedure was run successfully. If you need to return value you should use OUTPUT parameter;

```
CREATE PROC Valtest( @job_id INT, @result VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM employee  WHERE  job_id=@job_id)
    SET @result = 'Yes'; 
    ELSE 
    SET @result = 'No';  
END;

DECLARE @r NVARCHAR(100);
EXEC Valtest @job_id = 200, @result = @r OUTPUT;
SELECT @r;
```